# splitting string error: cannot convert from string to char

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following code:

```
textPath = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "JSONFiles/text_to_text.txt";
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(textPath);
 string text = reader.ReadLine();
 string[] colour = text.Split(",");
 m_textMeshPro.SetText(text);
 reader.Close();
```

The code is reading a line from txt file. I use this inside unity. But, there is a red line under the argument inside the split function (",") and when I hover over it. It says "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this, replace the double quotes with single quotes to specify a char.

```
string[] colour = text.Split(',');
```